# Limitar API google translate - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Coloquei a api do google translate no meu website, gostaria de saber como forçar ele a traduzir elementos específicos, ou forçar a não traduzir algum elemento, pois no website contem um cardápio, e o google translate faz a tradução incorreta dos itens, então fiz uma tradução manual, mas o google translate sempre força a substituir essa tradução.

Se não for possível limitar onde ele deve traduzir, tem como fazer o google translate parar de forçar a tradução depois de eu traduzir esse cardápio manualmente?

lembrando que depois do disparo do evento que faz a tradução, eu chamo minha tradução manual, e ele acaba por retraduzir.

OBS.: talvez pareça meio confuso, se precisarem de mais detalhes ou da parte do código do google translate que me refiro, posso mandar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar a classe `notranslate` no elemento que deseja que seja ignorado pelo google tradutor, por exemplo:

```html
<p>It's only a test using GoogleTranslate</p>
<p class="notranslate">It's only a test using GoogleTranslate</p>
<p>It's only a test using GoogleTranslate</p>
```

Após executar ficará assim:

> [image: resultado do google tradutor usando a classe notranslate]

Um detalhe, classes podem adicionar múltiplas classes em um elemento, por exemplo:

```html
<div class="foo bar baz notranslate boo">...</div>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, valeu amigo, muuito obrigado!! +1