Não traduzir um texto especifico do HTML
Atualmente tenho essa API do google translate, para deixar o site inteiro traduzido para a lingua selecionada, porem, eu gostaria que ele NÃO traduzisse certos texto como por exemplo e-mail do footer e etc, como faço?
<a href="javascript:trocarIdioma('es')"><img alt="espanhol" src="images/es.png"></a>
  <a href="javascript:trocarIdioma('en')"><img alt="ingles" src="images/en.png"></a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var comboGoogleTradutor = null; //Varialvel global

  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
          pageLanguage: 'pt',
          includedLanguages: 'en,es',
          layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
      }, 'google_translate_element');

      comboGoogleTradutor = document.getElementById("google_translate_element").querySelector(".goog-te-combo");
  }

  function changeEvent(el) {
      if (el.fireEvent) {
          el.fireEvent('onchange');
      } else {
          var evObj = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");

          evObj.initEvent("change", false, true);
          el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
      }
  }

  function trocarIdioma(sigla) {
      if (comboGoogleTradutor) {
          comboGoogleTradutor.value = sigla;
          changeEvent(comboGoogleTradutor);//Dispara a troca
      }
  }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>


Use a classe notranslate, segue instruções: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/474329/3635. Se o email não estiver em um elemento basta adicionar um span, exemplo: <footer> ... <span class="notranslate">foo@bar.baz</span> ... </footer>
